# Target dart2js failed, file not found issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hi I am trying to run flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety but I am getting the below error.
I followed the following steps :

1. after running flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety I got the error
2. On looking at various forums I ran flutter upgrade
3. After upgrade I ran flutter clean and flutter pub get but the error still persists.
4. Also ran flutter doctor -v but not getting any errors.
5. checked the location of the file and it is correct but still not able to find the location -- even though no changes was made to any of the location it suddenly started showing the error

If someone can please help me resolve this issue.

Let me know if you require any further information from my end.

error on running the above:

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
lib/providers//login_details.dart:1:8:
Error: Error when reading 'lib/providers/models/login_page.dart': Error reading 'lib/providers/models/login_page.dart'  (No such file or
directory)
import '../models/login_page.dart';
       ^
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.6, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.3.6 on channel stable at /Users/akhil/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 6928314d50 (5 days ago), 2022-10-25 16:34:41 -0400
    • Engine revision 3ad69d7be3
    • Dart version 2.18.2
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/akhil/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.50.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 107.0.5304.87

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

```
Flutter 3.3.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 6928314d50 (5 days ago) • 2022-10-25 16:34:41 -0400
Engine • revision 3ad69d7be3
Tools • Dart 2.18.2 • DevTools 2.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
lib/providers//login_details.dart:1:8:
Error: Error when reading 'lib/providers/models/login_page.dart': Error reading 'lib/providers/models/login_page.dart'  (No such file or
directory)
import '../models/login_page.dart';

Flutters say it cant find "login_page.dart';" this one.

You will follow simple steps.

---

Your dart page top import first -- import '../models/login_page.dart';

#Dart #Android_studio